# jQuery1.x selector click function not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, css-selectors, click

```
<img style="cursor:pointer" class="optStyle" 
src="/ekp/resource/style/default/icons/add.gif" title="添加行" 
onclick="DocList_AddRow();XFom_RestValidationElements();">
```

I am using jQuery1.x selector to get the element, and then use its click function to make it, but it does not work in Internet Explorer, Chrome is ok.

```
$( "img[title='添加行']").click()
```

Here is the effect image link （I do not have 10   reputation so I can not post images）
https://img.shownmmp.top/my.gif
I have tried jquery1.x in ie console (<kbd>f12</kbd>), but it does nothing. I have done it in Chrome and it works very well, what should I do now?

I want the click function to work in ie.
Also can you tell me how to make the img element clicked using javascript or jquery ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to make a test with code below and find that it is working fine with IE 11 and chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clk").click(function(){
   $( "img[title='添加行']").click();
  });
 
});

function abc()
{
alert("abc");
}
function xyz()
{
alert("xyz");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>



<button id="clk">click</button>

<img style="cursor:pointer" class="optStyle" 
src="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\plex-icon.png" title="添加行" 
onclick="abc();xyz();">
</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11:

[image]

You can try to make a test with this code on your side and let us know whether it is working or not.

Comment: Of  course your  html work in ie without trying ，I am wondering can you show me how to make the img click without button alternatively do id in ie console (f12)

Comment: now I know  where the problem exactly is ， apparently not the click function problem。 thank u

Comment: If your issue got solved than I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.